# OpenCV Python Mouse Event Unresponsive

Tags: python, opencv, mouseevent

I am trying to create an application using opencv, tkinter and python where people can tag their name on a photo. They write their name in a text field, and when they open the image through a GUI, they double click on the image to add their name. So, basically, when you click on the image, it is grabbing the text from a text box. I have checked effbot and the tkinter/python docs and opencv docs and I cannot see why the name from the text field will not show up on the image when I double click on it. I tried playing around with print statements to make sure that it was seeing the text from the text box and it is. The name of the text box is declared globally. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is not working? Thanks for any advice.

```
 """PAINT: TAG IMAGE WITH TEXT FROM TKINTER ENTRY FIELD"""
    img = cv2.imread('photoBoothOut.jpg',0)

def draw_text(event, x,y, flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        cv2.putText(img,nameTextField.get(), (x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (0,0,0), 2)
        print nameTextField.get()


def paint_canvas():
    cv2.namedWindow("Paint :: Press ESC to exit; Double Click to TAG")
    while(1):
        cv2.imshow("Paint :: Press ESC to exit; Double Click to TAG",img)
        cv2.setMouseCallback("image",draw_text)
        if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF ==27:
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

"""END PAINT"""
```

Comment: Are you sure this is tkinter? Tkinter doesn't have methods like `setMouseCallback` and `waitKey`.

Comment: That could be one of my problems. I am using a mix of Tkinter and OpenCV libraries. So it is possible I got them confused. Should I edit my question?

Comment: This is `openCV` code, that's ok. The really big problem you will face, independently of the yet missing `Tkinter` part of the code here, is on how to handle ( coordinate ) two separate <<eventLoop>> controllers ( one for the running `Tkinter`-MVC, the second for the `OpenCV`-MVC running in parallel )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your mouse callback goes to a non existing target / windowname.

if you choose a name like: "Paint :: Press ESC to exit; Double Click to TAG",

this has to go into the setMouseCallback(), too. (you have to be consistent with the naming):

```
def paint_canvas():
    winname="Paint :: Press ESC to exit; Double Click to TAG"
    cv2.namedWindow(winname)
    cv2.setMouseCallback(winname,draw_text)
    while(1):
        cv2.imshow(winname,img)
        if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF ==27:
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense because I had it working before, and then I started cleaning up my code to make it look better. Somewhere in there I must have messed the names up.